# UrlHelper for Web API angular js states

Tags: c#

I am just setting up the confirm email method in my Web API and I found this little bit of code:

```
var callbackUrl = new Uri(Url.Link("ConfirmEmailRoute", new { userId = userId, code = code }));
```

which converts a route into a valid Url along with query string parameters.
Before I write my own version I was wondering if there was already a method to do the same thing, but without a route.

For example, the above bit of code can return something like this:

> http://localhost:58127/api/users/Confirm?userId=something&code=another

but this is no good, I actually need to go to my application url which would be more like:

http://localhost:58127/#/users/confirm?userId=something&code=another

Comment: did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a little trick with extension:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string AngularLink(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string url, RouteValueDictionary data)
    {
        return urlHelper.Link(url, data).Replace("api/", "#/");
    }
}
```